# Is there a method to check if the screen is turned on or off?

Tags: android, screen, alarmmanager

I need a service to take gps updates, but only, when the screen is turned on. Is there a method to do this?
My idea was to work with a Alarm manager and a alarm reciever class that cheks  if the screen is turned on and af it is starting a service. But how could the Alarmreciever check if the screen is turned on?

Comment: you can use onStart and onPause (if your app is active). For more details read about activity life cycle management

Answer (score 2):

You can use this method to check if screens is on/off.

```
public boolean isScreenOn(Context context) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
        DisplayManager dm = (DisplayManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DISPLAY_SERVICE);
        boolean screenIsOn = false;
        for (Display display : dm.getDisplays()) {
            if (display.getState() != Display.STATE_OFF) {
                screenIsOn = true;
            }
        }
        return screenIsOn;
    } else {
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        //noinspection deprecation
        return pm.isScreenOn();
    }
}
```

Call it like

```
isScreenOn(YourActivity.this);
```

Comment: What should iI Enter as a context?

Comment: You seem new to Android. You can pass `this` if you are calling this method from Activity/Service.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        boolean isScreenOn = pm.isScreenOn();
        if (isScreenOn){
            //Screen is on
        }else {
            //Screen is off
        }
```

Comment: You should use Display.getState() for API >= 20 as above. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SCREEN_ON